# Object Pooling Waves

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've finally learned the basics of object pooling but I've ran into a problem. I used to call my spawn waves like so;

```
Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition1, spawnRotation1);
Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition2, spawnRotation2);
Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition3, spawnRotation3);
Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition4, spawnRotation4);
Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition5, spawnRotation5);
Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition6, spawnRotation6);
```

Now I have an object pool to dip into, I use the following;

```
GameObject enemy = ObjectPooler.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject("Enemy");                
if (enemy != null)
{
enemy.transform.position = spawnPosition1;
enemy.transform.rotation = spawnRotation1;
enemy.SetActive(true);
}
```

How would I go about spawning the other 5 enemies? Would I need to replicate the first enemy code another 5times? Seems like a lot of redundant code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use arrays and loops. This is basic c#.

Comment: I tried, I can't put the enemy object into a list because it cannot convert types. Would casting work here?

Comment: All your enemies would be gameobjects....

Comment: Took me a while to figure out but it worked in the end thanks guys! What you were saying made sense in my head it was just the implementation was hard. Once again thanks for pointing me in the right direction.